# How can I create a usort function php to list array an compare arrays

Tags: php, function, unit-testing, tdd, usort

I am still learning php I would like to discover how can I create a function compare and list using usort() for this array and debug render for phpunit?

```
// create an array with names to be sorted
$names = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// render the sorted names
$example = new \Example($names);
$example->renderNamesSorted();

function sortedNames (){

}
function renderNamesSorted (){

}
```

My actual output on php unit is

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
Array (
     0 => 'a'
-    1 => 'b'
-    2 => 'c'
+    1 => 'c'
+    2 => 'b'
 )
```

I would like create a function to compare and avoid not equal value in output phpunit

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @JulesR are expect to be not equal on array list, my actual render phpunit is Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected not equal on order not equal array list
+++ Actual

 Array (
     0 => 'a'
-    1 => 'c'
-    2 => 'b'
+    1 => 'b'
+    2 => 'c'
 )

Comment: please edit your question to include the expected output

Comment: @5th sure, I edited question trying to explain better and make it more clear :)